# Compile old LaTeX document

Tags: latex

Recently I found an old LaTeX document I've written in 1994. It starts with a line

```
\documentstyle[makeidx,twoside,german,bibgerm,a4wide,mydefs,
               equations,fleqn,psfig]{script}
```

Now I tried to compile this document using an actual version of MiKTeX on my windows machine, but pdflatex complains about an undefined contol sequences '\phspace':

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \uppercase {i}\phspace
                                  {1em}Fail--Stop
```

I'm very sure this document compiled without any errors in 1994 (it was my thesis). What can I do to make this compilable again?

Comment: After some search I found this 'phspace' sequence inside the version 2.09 of LaTeX (http://yytex.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/fonts/em/latex209/latex.tex). Do I have to switch back to this version? And how do I do that?

Comment: Yike! I hadn't noticed, but *I* don't have a 2.09 compatibility module anymore. When did that go away?

Comment: You might like to try latex and dvi2pdf, rather than pdflatex.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This looks like something that comes from the `toc` file. Do you still have all the auxiliary files produced by the old LaTeX in the same directory? If so, you should delete them before trying with a modern LaTeX. These include at least `aux`, `toc`, `lof`, and `lot`.

Comment: That's a very elegant solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think `\phspace` was probably an old LaTeX 2.09 primitive that is no longer used. Try adding

```
\let\phspace\hspace
```

in your preamble.

Comment: I think so too, I suspect that phspace is protected hspace ?